# Giving permission for each table within a database

Tags: security, permissions

I want to give different permission for different tables within a single database for a user.For example a user has full permission to a table while for another table only read permission.How it can be done within a database?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle (and, realistically, most any reasonable database), everything is denied other than what is granted.  So simply grant the user the privileges you want him to have

```
GRANT select, update, delete
   ON table_owner.table_name
   TO username;

GRANT select
   ON table_owner.another_table_name
   TO username;
```

Comment: Same with SQL Server.

Comment: Except that with SQL Server 2005+ it is `ON schema.table_name`. :-)